# Opening sqldatabase on pyqt shows nothing

Tags: python, sql, qt, pyqt

I tried to open `sqldatabase` (`.db` file), but it shows nothing on `pyqt` `QMainWindow`. The following is the code. Complete version is on [Github](https://github.com/longroadcomputing/PyQtDatabases) (written by MrAGi).

```
def open_database_file(self):
    path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(caption="Open Database",filter="Database file (*.db *.dat)")
    self.connection = SQLConnection(path)
    self.connection.open_database()

class SQLConnection():
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path
        self.db = None

    def open_database(self):
        if self.db:
            self.close_database()

        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        if QT_VERSION_STR < '5':
            path = self.path
        else:
            path = self.path[0]
        self.db.setDatabaseName(path)
        ok = self.db.open()
        return ok
```

Comment: I updated the title to better reflect your question. I improved the formatting and grammar for better readability.

Comment: You are just returning the result, not even printing it. How did you expect to show anything up?

Comment: This is just part of the code.And I don't know where the problem is.The entire code is on github. [link](https://github.com/kylekirkby/PyQt-and-SQL-Project)

Comment: @Ram Thank you for your effort!